# Java - How to use Wdsl2Java imported classes

Tags: java, soap, interface

i'm working on a thesis project about Java and Soap web services, I'm a bit new to Soap and all of this webservices.
What i'm going to do is to take some info from soap services that are already implemented and then make some processing on them with java and eclipse (that isn't my problem for now).

For now, what i've done is importing with command "wdsl2java" all the wdls services that i have (that thery are not done by me), in this way i have all the classes inside eclipse, and also an interface that implements some methods..

My question could be a lot stupid but, how can i use the classes imported in my project?
For example: what can i write on the main class to use data from soap services?
Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: Do you want to **call** the SOAP services, or **extract meta-information**?

Comment: i want to take some information, for example getting a particular id of an object and retrieve some info associated with it

Answer (score 0):

try to write a webservice client ,use your exposed webservice and play around with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, 
You may use SOAP UI to play around, instead of main class

Comment: Well i have soapUI where i can see all services, anyway after have played a bit, the objective was to retrieve with java some of that values :)